# Открытие сайта в стандартном браузере

Tags: activity, android, webbrowser

Мне нужно, чтобы по нажатию button  открывался сайт в стандартном браузере.
Подскажите, какой метод использовать вызова сайт в стандартном браузере?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого надо послать интент с адресом страницы:

```
String url="https://www.google.ru/search?q=android%20open%20url%20in%20browser&es_th=1&rct=j";
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
context.startActivity(browserIntent);
```